# Create cheat sheet for all users

Tags: 14.04, server

I created a cheat sheet for myself on ubuntu server.
But where do i need to copy the cheat file lets say "test" so that all users or other users can read that file too.

For example:
User Joe create cheat test

> cheat -e test

User Clair wants to read that file aswell

> cheat test

But gets the error cheat file not found.

How can i fix this ?

Comment: What is `cheat` in `cheat -e test`? Some command?

Comment: It a python command to create a "man" page on ubuntu server.
    "cheat <file> --> to read the file"
    "cheat -e <file> --> to create/edit the file"

Comment: Doesn't seem to be from Ubuntu: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cheat, https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=cheat,  http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=cheat

Comment: Its from python on Ubuntu server. But anyway i have found it. Thx for helping out. I was just wondering where to put the file in ubuntu so that all users can read the file, thats why i asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

File is located at `/home/Joe/.cheat/test`
Copy the file to `/home/Clair/.cheat/test`

and they can both read the cheat sheet.

Answer (score 3):

## Create public directory

When you want files to be shared by all users it is best to create a public directory where everyone has read access but only a select few have write access. For this purpose I would create a directory called:

```
/home/Public
```